# Blender Python: Property Description String Limit?

Tags: python, add-on, development

Is there a string length limit for the descriptions of properties? I assume there is. Does anyone know what that length is, and is there a safety mechanism to catch strings that are too long?

```
ScenePos : BoolProperty(
    name="title",
    description="this string is not very long",
    default=False
    )
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken by a quick look at the code, there doesn't seem to be a hard limit for properties, because they are `PyObject`s. This matches brockmann's test, which suggest that allocation simply fails at some very high number of bytes. For menus and operators there is a hard coded limit defined by `RNA_DYN_DESCR_MAX` which is 240.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Thanks for looking into the source and confirming that @rjg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender becomes laggy at `1000000000` and crashes at `10000000000` characters on my machine (64bit):

```
my_int: IntProperty(
    name = "Int Value",
    description=1000000000*"A",
    default = 23,
    min = 10,
    max = 100
    )
```

Comment: Haha, wow. I also tested this way, but I wasn't sure if they were error checking it. Are we positive the string isn't being written to unowned memory once it exceeds a certain threshold? I've seen overruns like that work correctly before.